# Visualforce Select checkbox empty in controller

Tags: salesforce, visualforce, apex

I have a string list in my controller

```
public List<String> m_lstChosenCloneOptions{get;set;}
```

with the following code in the page

```
<apex:selectCheckboxes value="{!m_lstChosenCloneItems}" layout="pageDirection">
                <apex:selectOptions value="{!CloneOptions}" />
            </apex:selectCheckboxes>
```

There are 3 options and I default all of the to checked by putting the keys into m_lstChosenCloneItems. It works because the page displays with all the items checked. I also have a button that when clicked starts a cloning process. However, the first line in the controller is a System.Debug(m_lstChosenCloneItems);  and it displays as empty.  I'm not sure how at the final line of the constructor the list is filled with the options but just clicking the button right after the page loads, the list is empty.

Update: I added the type above it is a public list.

Here is the button and controller:

```
<apex:commandButton value="Clone Project" action="{!cloneProject}" rerender="messagepanel"/>

  public void cloneProject()
  {
      System.Debug(m_lstChosenCloneOptions);
  }
```

FYI I was able to "fix" this by adding a javascript that grabs the checkboxes and passes in their values to an apex:param.  But I'm still curious why the binding with the list isn't working.  Maybe the function being void is the issue?

Comment: Can you please share the import part of the controller? and public m_lstChosenCloneOptions{get;set;} is hopefully a typo because the Type of this variable is missing. e.g. public List<String> m_lstChosenCloneOptions{get;set;}

Comment: Can you check after adding the type of `m_lstChosenCloneOptions` i.e. `public 'typename' m_lstChosenCloneOptions{get;set;} `